# Cannot handle 409 error In React using Axios

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, request

I am trying to handle the 409 error that receives in frontend, but nothing shows in the frontend, I just get a 409 (conflict), but no toast is shown.

THis is the only thing that shows in console, but none of the toast shows up.

[image]

Express.js

```
  return res.status(409).json({
        success: false,
        message: "The renting period already exists in the interval",
      });
```

React.js

AxiosAuth is an Axios Instance:

```
const instanceAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`,
});

instanceAxios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  if (token) {
    config.headers["token"] = token;
  }
  return config;
});


 try {
        await axiosAuth.post(`/service_provider/products`, values).then((res) => {
          if (res.status === 200 && res.data.success === true) {
            toast.success("Product was created successfully")
          } else if (res.status === 409) {
            toast.error("Conflict")
          }
        })
      } catch (err: unknown) {
        console.log("TESTS")
        if ((err as AxiosError).response) {
          if ((err as AxiosError).response?.status === 404) {
            console.log((err as AxiosError).response.data)
            navigate("/404")
          } else if ((err as AxiosError).response?.status === 409) {
            toast.error("Conflict")
          }
        } else {
          Swal.fire({
            title: "Error",
            text: "Failed to store product",
            icon: "error",
            confirmButtonText: "OK",
          })
        }
        setLoading(false)
      }
```

Comment: You're showing different code than what the error is for. It's for `/api/service_provider/renting_periods`, not for `/products`. Also, what is `return res.status(409).json({` coming from inside `Express.js`? You aren't showing anything helpful.

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu I am using a axiosInstance for that.

and res.status(409) is from Express.JS

Comment: @Wesley LeMahieu is correct your React file has everything to do with -> Products. and your Express.js throws an error for -> renting period. Show us the code in React.js that has this : `http://localhost:4500/api/service_provider/renting_periods` like your error is telling you.